# How to bind expanded event of WPF treeview item to the viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, treeview

I'm trying to bind the expanded event to the viewmodel (not the *.xaml.cs file) to extend the treeview only after expanding a node.

My approach is:

```
<TreeView x:Name="TreeViewTest" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Mode=OneTime}">
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="{Binding Title, Mode=OneTime}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TreeViewItem.Expanded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.ExpandedCommand, Source={x:Reference TreeViewTest}}">       </i:InvokeCommandAction>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TreeView>
```

I get following error message:

> Cannot call MarkupExtension.ProvideValue because of a cyclical dependency. Properties inside a MarkupExtension cannot reference objects that reference the result of the MarkupExtension. The affected MarkupExtensions are: 
>   System.Windows.Data.Binding

Can someone help me how to solve this error or is there another way to bind the event to a command in the viewmodel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can understand you try to attach a command to TreeViewItem.Expanded event.
I've done a small research concerning this issue and here is the result I've end up with.

1. There is  a small problem with the tree view items and this event.
2. There are several approaches to solve the problem:

First is AttachedProperties in style of the TreeViewItem, here is the link:
[Invoke Command when TreeViewItem is Expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316932/invoke-command-when-treeviewitem-is-expanded)

Second is Behavior involved solution:

1. XAML:

   ```
   <Grid>
   <TreeView x:Name="TreeViewTest" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" TreeViewItem.Expanded="TreeViewTest_OnExpanded">
       <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
           <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type soTreeViewHelpAttempt:TreeObject}" 
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Mode=OneTime}">
               <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                       <StackPanel>
                           <Label Content="{Binding }" />
                       </StackPanel>
                   </DataTemplate>
               </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
               <StackPanel>
                   <Label Content="{Binding Title, Mode=OneTime}" />
               </StackPanel>
           </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
       </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
       <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
           <soTreeViewHelpAttempt:TreeViewItemExpandBehavior OnExpandedAction="{Binding OnExpandedActionInViewModel}"/>
       </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
   </TreeView></Grid>
   ```
2. ViewModel:

   ```
       public MainDataContext()
   {
       OnExpandedActionInViewModel = new Action<object, RoutedEventArgs>(OnExpanded);
   }

   public Action<object, RoutedEventArgs> OnExpandedActionInViewModel
   {
       get { return _onExpandedActionInViewModel; }
       private set
       {
           _onExpandedActionInViewModel = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Behavior Command property:

   ```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty OnExpandedActionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
       "OnExpandedAction", typeof (Action<object,RoutedEventArgs>), typeof (TreeViewItemExpandBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(Action<object,RoutedEventArgs>)));

   public Action<object,RoutedEventArgs> OnExpandedAction
   {
       get { return (Action<object,RoutedEventArgs>) GetValue(OnExpandedActionProperty); }
       set { SetValue(OnExpandedActionProperty, value); }
   }
   ```
4. Behavior code:

   ```
       protected override void OnAttached()
   {
       base.OnAttached();
       AssociatedObject.Loaded += AssociatedObjectOnLoaded;
   }

   private void AssociatedObjectOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   {
       var treeView = sender as TreeView;
       if(treeView == null) return;
       treeView.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().ToList().ForEach(o =>
       {
           var treeViewItem = treeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(o) as TreeViewItem;
           if(treeViewItem == null) return;
           treeViewItem.Expanded += TreeViewItemOnExpanded;
           _list.Add(treeViewItem);
       });
   }

   private void TreeViewItemOnExpanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   {
       if(OnExpandedAction == null)
           return;
       OnExpandedAction(sender, routedEventArgs);
   }


   protected override void OnDetaching()
   {
       base.OnDetaching();
       AssociatedObject.Loaded -= AssociatedObjectOnLoaded;
       _list.ForEach(item => item.Expanded -= TreeViewItemOnExpanded);
       _list.Clear();
   }
   ```

I hope It will help you.
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

To create Binding to TreeView you must use RelativeSource Self, but not Source with x:Reference.
For example here i'm binding Width of TreeView to Height:

```
<TreeView Name="tv" Width="{Binding Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

</TreeView>
```

Or also you can use ElementName, like here:

```
<TreeView Name="tv" Width="{Binding Height, ElementName=tv}">

</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but there's an obvious solution that does not require any custom code.

When using `i:EventTrigger`, you can specify the object to listen the event from as below, where I'm using `RelativeSource` binding to walk up the visual tree and find a `TreeViewItem`.

Also, you can bind to an element by name using `ElementName`, which doesn't cause circular dependencies because bindings work on the dispatcher when the controls are already created and initialized (unlike `x:Reference`, which has to be resolved during XAML deserialization).

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger SourceObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}}" EventName="Expanded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=TreeView, Path=DataContext.ExpandedCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```